# .htaccess regex replace dashes by underscore

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

For some reason a colleague replaced dashed by underscores in our website's URL.

I would like to 301 the old URLs to the new ones using a regex in our .htaccess

I found this code that works very well as intended, it is supposed to do the opposite, it replaces underscore with dashes :

```
RewriteEngine     On
RewriteRule       ^(/?articles/.*/[^/]*?)_([^/]*?_[^/]*)$ $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule       ^(/?articles/.*/[^/]*?)_([^/_]*)$       $1-$2 [R=301]
```

But for some reason i ignore why it does not work if i invert the logic

```
RewriteEngine     On
RewriteRule       ^(/?articles/.*/[^/]*?)-([^/]*?-[^/]*)$ $1_$2 [N]
RewriteRule       ^(/?articles/.*/[^/]*?)-([^/-]*)$       $1_$2 [R=301]
```

Even if i escape the dashes, it won't work, any ideas or corrections are welcome

Comment: umm, you want to replace `-` with `_` or vice versa? And do your links also have `articles/` path?

Comment: If structures of URLs are changed from *dashed* to *underscored* then why there should be a reason for second rules to work?

Comment: Actually i want to replace dashes with underscore, here is my old URL :

    http://example.com/articles/whatever/my-old-article

my new URL : 

    http://example.com/articles/whatever/my_old_article

Either nothing happens, either i get a strange absolutepath redirect like this :

    http://example.com/home/user/public_html/web/sites/default/my_old_article . I get this absolutepath thing when i add a L : [R=301,L]

Comment: Ok i see that there is something wrong in my syntax, but can't find a way to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess with [`DPI` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_dpi):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(articles/[^-]*)-+([^-]*-.*)$ $1_$2 [N,NC,DPI]

RewriteRule ^(articles/[^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /$1_$2 [NE,L,NC,R=301]
```

The `DPI` flag causes the `PATH_INFO` portion of the rewritten URI to be discarded.

Comment: Awesome! works like a charm! i really need to work on my regex knowledge, it's so usefull, thanks a lot!